# Make a button in CMS page call a controller

Tags: cms, controllers

I want to have a button on the CMS page that calls a controller. The CMS content is:

```
<p>{{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}cmsmanager/export/params</p>
```

This line produces the url that , if I copy it and paste into a browser, calls ExportController and the method params as expected so it looks like its configured correctly.

But the next two lines show buttons with the correct label but do not open the link:

```
<p><input type="button" onclick="window.open({{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}cmsmanager/export/params);" value="Window Open" /></p>
```

OR

```
<p><input type="button" onclick="setLocation({{config path="web/secure/base_url"}}cmsmanager/export/params);" value="Set Location" /></p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `onclick="location.href='{{store url="cmsmanager/export/params"}}'"`.

Comment: Thanks, I missed the single quotes. How does store url  differ from the config path="web/secure/base_url  ?

Comment: `{{sotre ..}}` is a shortcut for `getUrl(..)` where arguments are passed to the method and processed while `{{config path ..}}` just returns the base URL and then you put the rest of your path afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

This will also work.

```
<p><input onclick="window.location.href='{{store url="cmsmanager/export/params"}}'" type="button" value="Window Open" /></p>
```